# Error when plotting contour with matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot such a function. However, the following code will cause an error. I think that the cause is that a scalar value is returned in `norm ()`, but how can it be solved?[image: function]

The label of the image represents the definition formula, the search space, the optimal solution from the left

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.05) 
y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.05) 

X ,Y= np.meshgrid(x, y)
print(X)
c1 = -2 * np.ones((2,200,200))
c2 = 4 * np.ones((2,200,200))
print(np.linalg.norm(np.array([X,Y]) - c1))
Z = (1 - 1 / (1 * np.linalg.norm(np.array([X,Y]) - c1) + 1)) + (1 - 1 / (2 * 
np.linalg.norm(np.array([X,Y]) - c2) + 1))
plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z,cmap='hsv') 
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your current `Z` is not of same dimension as your `X` and `Y`. This could be verified by printing the shape of X, Y and Z. The reason is that you did not provide an `axis` while computing the `norm` in your equation and hence you were getting a scalar value. You can refer to the [Official docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) for more info on how the `axis` argument works. In your case, since you did not specify any value for the `axis`, it was returning you a *matrix norm* instead of a *vector norm*

Below is the solution where you provide `axis=0` to compute the norm properly for column wise entry combinations of your `X` and `Y`

```
Z = (1 - 1 / (1 * np.linalg.norm(np.array([X,Y]) - c1, axis=0) + 1)) + (1 - 1 / (2 *np.linalg.norm(np.array([X,Y]) - c2,  axis=0) + 1))
plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z,cmap='hsv')
```

[image]